# Change default boolean value with OrmLite in DB

Tags: java, ormlite

I have boolean column in my DB (.sqlite3). It may be 0 or 1.

```
public static final String DISABLE_CATEGORY = "disable_category";
@DatabaseField(columnName = DISABLE_CATEGORY)
private boolean disable;
```

How can I change the value to 't' or 'f'?

Comment: you have to use `String` if you want to have 't' or 'f'

Answer (score 2):

Try changing boolean to Boolean

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, defaultValue = "true")
private Boolean mIsEnabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  Boolean to boolean

```
@DatabaseField(columnName = Database.TABLE.User.isCustomer)
public boolean isCustomer ;(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.TABLE.User.isCustomer))==0)?false:true,
```